# Архивация файла

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно заархивировать отдельный файл, видео или картинку в архив на wpf?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словом заархивировать? Сжать? И да, большинство форматов изображений и видео уже являются сжатыми.

Comment: Дв, сжать и поместить в архив с расширением .zip или .rar

Comment: @user222335 выбрать файл в программе написанной на WPF и потом заархивировать его, это нужно?

Comment: Используйте классы `ZipFile` и `ZipArchive`

Comment: WPF — это графический фреймворк. Причём он к архивированию файлов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com)

Пример использования: создание архива

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
     // add the report into a different directory in the archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
     zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
     zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
 }
```

И о сжатии файлов, подробнее [читайте здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.7.php) и [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужен инструментарий из [System.IO.Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Пример создания архива `C:\result.zip`, содержащего файл `C:\data.txt`:

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\result.zip", FileMode.Create))
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"C:\data.txt", "data.txt");
}
```

Для использования метода расширения CreateEntryFromFile необходимо подключить сборку `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`.

Рекомендую изучить следующее руководство: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Архивирование - это очень обширное понятия. Если речь идёт о создании архивного файла в одном из распространённых форматов, то смотри ответы пользователей.

Если же тебе необходимо просто сжать файл для того чтобы уменьшить объем, и хранить его хоть на файловой системе, хоть в оперативной памяти, подойдёт более легковесный [GZipStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сначала сжать файл нужно, а потом закинуть в архив